# how to insert some formula in mysql?

Tags: mysql, select, formula

i want to calculating one row at table "counter". i try to make my table like:

```
name          black     yellow     white        qty_job      total
david           1        0          0            2             ?
andrew          0        1          1            4              ?
```

the formula to calculate is :

```
total = (nblack * 1) + (nyellow * 1) + (nwhite * 0.4) / qty_job
total = (1 * 1) + (0 * 1) + (0 * 0.4) / 2 = 0.5
```

how to insert this formula at mysql code? especially at SELECT method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't / can't make a row with a certain formula in it. You should use this query to retrieve the total:

```
SELECT
    name,
    black,
    yellow,
    white,
    qty_job
    (SUM(black) + SUM(yellow) + SUM(white)*0.4) / qty_job AS total
FROM counter
GROUP BY name;
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to create a view :

```
CREATE VIEW test AS
SELECT id, (black * 1) + (yellow * 1) + (white * 0.4) / qty_job as total FROM counter;
```

The rest should be easy, you could do something like this :

```
select
 counter.id,
 black,
 yellow,
 white,
 test.total
from
 counter,
 test
where
  counter.id = test.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Number As int, @Number2 As int
SET @Number = 5
WHILE @Number >= 1
BEGIN
PRINT @Number
SET @Number = @Number - 1

PRINT @Number2
SET @Number2 = @Number * (@Number2 - 1)

PRINT 'The Factorial of'
PRINT @Number
PRINT 'is'
PRINT @Number2

END 
GO
```